# Specify timezone for \today and \currenttime

Tags: luatex, latexmk, datetime

Is there a way I can specify the timezone LaTeX should use when printing the `\today` and `\currenttime` (or the datetime package in general)?

I need this because [travisCI](http://travisci.org) does build my PDF automatically on every commit and their timezone seems to be set to GMT. I'd need GMT+1.

Contrary to some other questions I don't want the timezone to be displayed, I just want the date & time to be in the specified timezone.

For building I use `latexmk` with pdflatex set to LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I set now the environment variable "TZ" to be "Europe/Zurich" and it seems to work at least on my local machine. Will try it on travis as well now. If it works, I'll close it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you find a solution that works wel, you could provide an answer to your own question rather than cloing it. Remember that others may want to solve similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the edit & the info (sorry for not formatting it properly). Yes that's what I actually intended to do - wrong naming ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Immediately after asking this question an idea came to my mind which worked out.

In order to specify the timezone you can just set the usual linux environment variable `TZ` before building the PDF.

As an example if you have a `Makefile` which builds it on running `make` you can set it like this:
`TZ='Europe/Zurich' make`

Or, of course, export it before running the build using `export TZ='Europe/Zurich'`.